# Why can't my NSOperation object receive async call back?

Tags: asynchronous, delegates, callback, nsoperation

I subclass NSOperation to implement my operation.Let's call it MyOperation.

In the implementation of MyOperation, I override the main function and inside it I create some async network stuff and set the delegate to self(the operation object).But the operation objects never get those delegate callbacks, why? I didn't set finished before the callback are received.

Or does NSOperation just can't do that?

I find that if I manually "start" the operation, it will work. But if I add it to a operation queue, the operation is excuted but just can't get those callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're setting up your callback in the main method like this:

```
-(void)main{
    // setup
    object.delegate = self
}
```

then your main method will continue execution, complete, and go away before the delegate has a chance to complete the callback. You either need to override the start method in NSOperation and manually handle the isFinished and isExecuting properties, or you need to figure out a way to have the delegate method get called on an object that isn't going away.

See the [NSOperation class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html) for full details on overriding the proper methods and KVC notifications to make it work.